# ArrayList get method out of bounds

Tags: java, arraylist

I've been working on creating a small shades method, but keep coming up with the same `IndexOutOfBoundsException` error.  I wouldn't think that I'm missing much to this?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Shades {

    public static String shades(String hex, int offset) {
        hex = hex.replace("#", "");
        String[] rgb_hex = hex.split(".{2}");
        ArrayList<Integer> rgb_int = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String i : rgb_hex) {
            int intg = Math.min(255, Math.max(
                    0, Integer.parseInt(i, 16) + offset));
            rgb_int.add(intg);
        }
        return String.format("%02x%02x%02x", rgb_int.get(0), 
            rgb_int.get(1), rgb_int.get(2));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(shades("#000000", 20));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making the assumption that `hex.split(".{2}");` returns an array with 3 elements.  I suspect this is not the case.   If you debug to that line you should see that the array list has less than 3 elements.  I believe a string with no periods will do this to you.  Maybe you need to throw an `IllegalArgumentExceprtion` or something if less than 3 elements is discovered.

Then when you do:

```
    return String.format("%02x%02x%02x", rgb_int.get(0), 
        rgb_int.get(1), rgb_int.get(2));
```

This will generate the exception if `rgb_int` does not have 3 elements.  The line number in the exception should give you the clue.

In the future, it is always a good idea to at least the relevant lines of the exception in your SO post and to show which lines correspond to it.

Answer (score 1):

Gray's right.  `hex.split(".{2}")` splits `hex` on any two characters.  If x has even length, say 10, then it splits on after the first two characters, after characters 2 and 4, etc.  A test gives an empty array.

You need to iterate over the characters un the string.  Java 8 may have an `Iterator` for this, but until then, you need:

```
public class Shades {
    public String shades(String hex, int offset) {
        hex = hex.replace("#", "");
        if (hex.length() != 6) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can only handle 6-hex " + 
                "character RGB strings.");
        }
        List<String> rgbHex = splitIntoPairs(hex);
        List<Integer> rgbInt = convertToInt(rgbHex, offset);

        return String.format("%02x%02x%02x", rgbInt.get(0), 
            rgbInt.get(1), rgbInt.get(2));
    }

    public List<String> splitIntoPairs(String s) {
        List<String> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
        pairs.add(s.substring(0, 2));
        pairs.add(s.substring(2, 4));
        pairs.add(s.substring(4, 6));
        return pairs;
    }

    public List<Integer> convertToInts(List<String> s, int offset) {
        List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<();
        for (String pair: s) {
            ints.add(bound(0, Integer.parseInt(s, 16) + offset, 255);
        }
        return ints;
    }

    public int bound(int lower, int x, int upper) {
        if (x < lower) {
            return lower;
        } else if (x > upper) {
            return upper;
        } else {
            return x;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shades shades = new Shades();
        System.out.println(shades.shades("#000000", 20));
    }
}
```

Note the way the methods are split up and given better names.